# Jenkins groovy regex match string : Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get the matched string from a regex in groovy. The matched string prints to the console  without problems, but when I try use the matched string in a git command I get the following error:

```
Err: Incremental Build failed with Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

Here is the code:

```
                def binaryName = "298_application_V2_00_Build_07.hex"

                def matches = (binaryName =~ /(V)(\d+)(_)(\d+)(_)(Build)(_)(\d+)/)
                versionTag = ""+matches[0].getAt(0)                 
                echo "${matches}"
                echo "$versionTag"
                bat("git tag $versionTag")
                bat("git push origin --tags")
```

How can I get the matched string from the regex?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This problem is caused by Jenkins' [CPS](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin), which serializes all pipeline executions to store as resumable state.

Calls to non-serializable methods have to be wrapped in a method annotated with `@NonCPS`:

```java
@NonCPS
String getVersion(String binaryName) {
  def matches = (binaryName =~ /(V)(\d+)(_)(\d+)(_)(Build)(_)(\d+)/)
  versionTag = ""+matches[0].getAt(0)
  versionTag
}
```

this method can now be called from your pipeline. In case your Jenkins master restarts during execution of this method, it would just run through it completely - which is in many cases, such as yours, absolutely no problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been struggling with this for some hours now. How is one supposed to know about this :\

Answer (score 1):

The NonCPS annotation did not have any effect in my declarative pipeline library.  A workaround is to avoid ever returning a matcher as shown in this example:

```
version = ("release/1.0.0" =~ /(?:release|hotfix)\/(.*)/)[0][1]
```