# How to extract string from commit-Message in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am a beginner in the usage of jenkins groovy-pipelines and I would like to extract a Substring (a Jira-Issue-ID) from a git-commit-Message and if the substring exists I would like to send a mail to a specified mail-address (the Jira-Mail-Handler). At the moment I try this it with this code:

```
    node {
      stage('Checkout') {
        git credentialsId: '74190aae-546c-499d-bec6-2d4fa59ac79c', url: 'https://git.example.com/testrepo'
      }

      stage('Jira') {
          def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B | cat')
          def matcher = (commit =~ '.*(TEST-[0-9]*).*')

          if (matcher)
          {
            mail bcc: '', body: 'BUILD_URL', cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: matcher[0][1]+'Build was successfully', to: 'jira@example.com'
          }
      }
    }
```

but then I get an error with:

```
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

so I start searching and found [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646409/jenkins-groovy-regex-match-string-error-java-io-notserializableexception-jav?rq=1) and so I try to write this code:

```
    @NonCPS
    def getCommitMsg() {
          def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B | cat')
          def matcher = (commit =~ '.*(TEST-[0-9]*).*')
          return matcher ? matcher[0][1] : null
    }

    node {
      stage('Checkout') {
        git credentialsId: '74190aae-546c-499d-bec6-2d4fa59ac79c', url: 'https://git.example/testrepo'
      }

      stage('Jira') {
          if (!getCommitMsg())
          {
            echo "Mail send!!!"
            mail bcc: '', body: 'BUILD_URL', cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'Build was successfully', to: 'john.doe@example.com'
          }
      }
    }
```

for my pipeline, but with this code groovy/jenkins didn't enter the if-Statement and now I think I need a little bit help and I would very thanksful if someone can give me a little hint what I am doing wrong?
best regards
Dan

Comment: For people who facing the same problem the first code works, my jenkins environment was broken

Answer (score 0):

```
   node {
      stage('Checkout') {
        git credentialsId: '74190aae-546c-499d-bec6-2d4fa59ac79c', url: 'https://git.example.com/testrepo'
      }

      stage('Jira') {
          def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B | cat')
          sh "bash -xe path/to/something.sh"
      }
    }
```

just exec a shell scripts .

```
path/to/something.sh 
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $commit =~ '*TEST-[0-9]*' ]]  ; then 
    #do llike sendemail
fi
```