# Update version following semver with groovy in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm currently trying to automate the versioning of my maven project with a Jenkins (version 2.190.3) job and following the SemVer. So I have my Jenkinsfile and I'm doing something like that:

```
script {
   def version = "1.2.4"
   def pattern = ~/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,4}$/
   def newVersion = version.replaceFirst(pattern) { _,major,minor -> "${major}.${(minor as int) + 1}.0"}
}
```

The expectation is to have 1.3.0 in **newVersion**.
The code seems OK, working on web console but when I'm using Jenkins I have the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot execute null+1

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: This post here answers almost the exact same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646409/jenkins-groovy-regex-match-string-error-java-io-notserializableexception-jav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the exact answer to your question is given in this post: [Jenkins groovy regex match string : Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646409/jenkins-groovy-regex-match-string-error-java-io-notserializableexception-jav)

What it comes down to is that the script executed by Jenkins is kind of groovy, but not exactly executed as it is. It is transformed first to a serializable state (can be suspended, saved to file, transported, restored, resumed).

This doesn't work with certain objects that have state, but aren't serializable, including `java.util.regex.Matcher`, which is working under the hood of your regular expression. If you put this code in a method marked `@NonCPS`, the code is not transformed, and (more of less) executed as plain groovy.

```
@NonCPS
def foo() {
  def version = "1.2.4"
  def pattern = ~/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,4}$/
  def newVersion = version.replaceFirst(pattern) { _,major,minor -> "${major}.${(minor as int) + 1}.0"}
  println "Version ${version} -> new ${newVersion}"
}

script {
    foo()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That was clear and it's working well.